# Update Profile Photo using XMPPFrameWork in IOS

Tags: ios, photo, user-profile, xmppframework

I am working on a chat app. Now there is a concept of profile photo. Can anyone tell me how can I change, update my profile photo and how other user can retrieve my profile photo .

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To publish avtar image you have to use [XEP-0084](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html)
And to downloading user avatar  you can use [XEP-0153](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html#bizrules-vcard)

The process for publishing and updating user avatars is as follows
**Keypoint from XEP-0084**

1. User publishes avatar data for "image/png" content-type to data node and optionally publishes other content-types to HTTP URLs.
2. User publishes notification of updated avatar to metadata node, with ItemID that matches SHA-1 hash of image data for "image/png" content-type (note: this is a hash of the image data itself, not the base64-encoded version).
3. Subscribers receive notification.
4. Optionally (and if necessary), subscribers retrieve avatar data identified by ItemID from data node using pubsub retrieve-items feature (or via HTTP).
5. Optionally, user disables avatar display.

Note: Before publishing avatar data and metadata, the user MUST determine if his or her server supports the PEP subset of pubsub by following the procedures specified in [XEP-0163](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html), since such support simplifies avatar publication. The following examples assume the availability of a PEP service.

Comment: XEP-0084 isnt supported by XMPPFramework. See list of supported XEP's https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/XEPs